# Query using joins and satisfying conditions

Tags: php, mysql

i have this query which i use to match two tables, now, i match the tables only by the time, so, which means, the time field in retailer table is 5 seconds earlier then the time field in imovo table. What i already need to achieve is:

When i insert a retailer row, i add info like retailer time, retailer epos_id
When i insert imovo row, i add info like imovo time, imovo rpos_id
I also have a table rbpos_epos which has matching rbpos_id and epos_id i.e

```
table retailer:
time     |    epos_id
12:23:34   ea12

table imovo
time     |    rbpos_id
12:23:29      ra12

table rbpos_epos
id  | epos_id  |   rbpos_id
1       ea12         ra12
```

When i match retailer with imovo, i want also to check whether their respective rbpos_id and epos_id match in the rbpos_epos table.. i mean, if they are a pair, if they have the same id..

here's the query i currently use

```
SELECT retailer.date, retailer.time, retailer.location, retailer.user_id,imovo.mobile_number ".
 "FROM retailer LEFT JOIN imovo ".
    " ON addtime(retailer.time, '0:0:50')>imovo.time
AND retailer.time <imovo.time AND retailer.date=imovo.date
"
```

Comment: Why don't you join the tables via `rbpos_epos`?

Comment: Can you please explain me better? i mean i know i should do something like join.. but i have no idea..

Comment: `FROM retailer JOIN rbpos_epos USING (epos_id) JOIN imovo USING (rbpos_id)`?

Comment: I get th elogic, i really do, i mean i know the logic behind this, the syntax is what i don't know how to apply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try joining all three tables [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52ab3/1/0)

```
select r.`time`, r.`epos_id`,
       i.`time`, i.`rbpos_id`
from retailer r
join rbpos_epos re on r.epos_id = re.epos_id
join imovo i on i.rbpos_id = re.rbpos_id
             and addtime(r.`time`, '0:0:50') > i.`time`
             and r.`time` < i.`time`
             and r.`date` = i.`date`;
```

Add columns in select as needed.

Comment: Can you please use my query?
I'm sorry, but this is difficult to me!

Comment: @al_alb When you join all three tables on `epos_id` and `rbpos_id`, you don't need to join on `date` and `time` fields anymore. I've added a SQL Fiddle to show it.

Comment: Well, there must be a double condition, which means, the date time and rbpos_id and epos id.. because there might be many rows that satisfy the rbpos_id epos_id part.

Comment: @al_alb Ok, I just appended the additional condition to the join clause. See also the modified SQL Fiddle. BTW, why don't you combine your `date` and `time` into a `datetime` column?

Comment: Thank you Olaf, i'll try to implement it now!
Well, you're right, but, the table in csv comes like this, so i've separated date and time :